# Append values to the same column in a for loop [R]

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, data.table, plyr

I have a data frame called `dt` -

```
dt <- data.frame(a_check=c(NA,2,1,NA,NA),
                 b_check=c(NA,1,1,NA,1))
```

I am trying to create a new column called `error` using `ifelse` condition to store all errors appended in that column with a row number of a corresponding  `NA`

sample code-

```
for(i in 1:length(colnames(dt))){
  ## NA check for a_check column
  dt$error <- ifelse(is.na(dt[colnames(dt)[i]]),"Missing Value found in a_check on row number - ",NA)
  ## NA check for b_check column
  dt$error <- ifelse(is.na(dt[colnames(dt)[i]]),"Missing Value found in b_check on row number - ",NA)
}
```

However, I want to append error messages from a_check & b_check in the same column.

Desired Output-

```
> dt
  a_check b_check                                           error
1      NA      NA     Missing Value found in a_check on row number - 1 &  Missing Value found in b_check on row number - 1
2       2       1                                            <NA>
3       1       1                                            <NA>
4      NA      NA     Missing Value found in a_check on row number - 4 &  Missing Value found in b_check on row number - 4
5      NA       1     Missing Value found in a_check on row number - 5
```

**Note- I want to `paste` row number and want to append error messages in the same column in a for loop. Also, I have more than 500 columns, that is the reason I am using for loop.

Comment: Why are you running that code in a for loop over the rows?

Comment: updated the code. thanks for pointing out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dt)[, error := if(any(is.na(.SD))) paste(c(.BY$rn, names(dt)[is.na(.SD)]), collapse=" "), 
    by=.(rn=seq_len(dt[,.N]))]
```

output:

```
   a_check b_check                   error
1:      NA      NA       1 a_check b_check
2:       2       1                    <NA>
3:       1       1                    <NA>
4:      NA      NA 4 a_check b_check error
5:      NA       1         5 a_check error
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are fixed on have the rownames pasted into the new column then using a `for` loop and a series of `if` statements might be the best way to. The issue with you trying to use `ifelse` is that you have more than two conditions, both error, a error, b error and no error.

Solution without using `ifelse`

```
 x<-c()

for(i in 1:nrow(dt)){
  if(is.na(dt[i,"a_check"]) & is.na(dt[i,"b_check"])){
    x<- c(x,paste("Missing Value found in a_check & b_chekc", rownames(dt)[i]))
  }else if(is.na(dt[i,"a_check"])){
    x<- c(x,paste("Missing Value found in a_check", rownames(dt)[i]))
  }else if(is.na(dt[i,"b_check"])){
    x<- c(x,paste("Missing Value found in b_check", rownames(dt)[i]))
  }else{
   x<- c(x,NA)
  }
}

dt$error <- x
```

### Update

As you pointed out that there is 500 columns which wouldn't work so you can try this

```
# Create error message matrix
z<-sapply(colnames(dt), function(i){
ifelse(is.na(x[,i]),paste("Missing Value found in", i, sep =" "), NA)
  })
# Collapse matrix, no error will be an empty string  
error<-apply(z,1,function(i){
  paste(i[!is.na(i)], collapse = " & ")
})

dt$error <- error
```

Comment: I have more than 500 columns. So, I guess above solution won’t work for that.

Comment: 500 columns? are you wanting to search each column for missing values?

Comment: Yes and append errors corressponding to that row for every column in error field. Thats why I am using for loop, otherwise its pretty straight forward for 2 columns

Comment: Yes, I think how I would attempt this would be create a matrix of each of the conditions and then appended them altogether. I will update my answer.

Comment: I am getting error  `Error in `[.data.frame`(x, , i) : undefined columns selected` while running sapply statement.